# Is there a function like WaitNamedPipe or a way to realize this on C++/linux? (so the process is not blocking on the pipe for infinite time)

Tags: c++, linux, wait, fifo, mkfifo

I have a named pipe in my C++ program. A childprocess writes a value in it and the parent process reads it. I created the pipe by mkfifo and all operations are blocking (fifo cannot be opened for reading before it is tried to open for writing and v.v. 
unfortunately sometimes my childprocess does not stop because of an error in a program the childprocess runs. It is not my task to fix this error in this external program but I want to make sure that the parent process does not stop for infinite time on the blocked open fifo call, but goes on after some time (without reading the value in the pipe).

So what I need it somethings like the WaitNamedPipe function. This function waits until either a time-out interval elapses or an instance of the specified named pipe is available for connection. http://ist.marshall.edu/ist480acp/namedpipes.html#WaitNamedPipe

Another way to realize this of course also works. I tried it with a loop in the parent process in which it always tries to open the pipe for reading and then sleeps if open is not possible. 
That seems to have no effect, probably because the parent process is blocking on the first open call.

Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 3):

You want `O_NONBLOCK` in your [`open(2)`](http://www.kernel.org/doc/man-pages/online/pages/man2/open.2.html) flags, see [`fifo(7)`](http://www.kernel.org/doc/man-pages/online/pages/man7/fifo.7.html). Then use [`select(2)`](http://www.kernel.org/doc/man-pages/online/pages/man2/select.2.html) or [`poll(2)`](http://www.kernel.org/doc/man-pages/online/pages/man2/poll.2.html) to wait for input (with a timeout).

Answer (score 2):

You can use a non-blocking pipe and `select()` call with a timeout. Or you can use a blocking `read()` call having called `alarm()` before it.

Comment: What implication does a non-blocking pipe have? In general, the blocking is good I think, just in the case (which is not often) that the child process does not finish, it should not block too long.

Comment: Scroll down to PIPE_BUF on http://www.kernel.org/doc/man-pages/online/pages/man7/pipe.7.html

Comment: `alarm` + `read` is a bad idea because it has an unavoidable race condition:  The alarm might go off before the `read` has a chance to start.  (Linux is not a real-time operating system, so in there is no guaranteed bound on the length of time between the call to `alarm` and the call to `read`.)  `select` (or `poll`) with a timeout works fine and is the correct answer.

Comment: It might. The value of using `alarm()` is that it is an easy code change.